# Cannot locate the "Multi Resolution" tab

Tags: interface, sculpting

I'm reading a relatively old book on Blender (The Essential Blender), which covers version 2.44 of the software.

Though I'm using version 2.72 of the software, I've been able to work my way around most changes since the version referenced by the book. However, in the chapter I'm currently covering (*Sculpting and Multiresolution Modeling*), I've seemed to have hit a bit of a road block. Here's what a quote from the book:

"*Let's make the cube "multiresolution". RMB to select the cube and press "Add Multires" in the Multires Panel of the Edit Buttons (F9).*"

Maybe I'm blind, but I can't seem to find this 'Multires" tab anywhere.

In version 2.72, where is the tab located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is the [*Multiresoultion* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Multiresolution). It is in the *Modifiers* tab under the *Generate* category.

[image]